# replace HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\callto\shell\open\command with c#

Tags: c#-4.0, registry, skype

I want to replace all the Skype / callto references in the windows registry so I can use something other than Skype.  How would I do this with c#

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\callto\shell\open\command
```

I'd like to use my own exe so install my app and then change the registry, also when I uninstall I need to set it back!

Comment: Are you asking how to write Registry keys in C#? See the documentation.

Comment: yes, or can I do this another way. I want to by pass skype once installed t use my app instead, is it recommended to do via registry

Comment: only to change the registry on installing the app

Comment: Use the [Registry class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx)